# SQL evaluation of IF clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Apologies if this is not suitable, but really this is a 'why' rather than a 'how'.  Not sure that is suitable, but don't know a better place to ask and I can't think how to phrase a google to get what I am looking for.

```
    IF 'hell' = 'freezing over'
    BEGIN
    SELECT log(0)
    END
```

Look at that statement.  There is no world in which the IF clause will be true. If I attempt to run it I am expecting SQL to jump past the IF clause and move to the end.  Instead I get:

```
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

This is bizarre.  So I guess that is just the way that SQL does it's thing. Except...

```
    IF 'hell' = 'freezing over'
    BEGIN
    SELECT 1/0
    END
```

There is no error here.  The statement in the IF clause should still generate an error.  Could anyone explain why this is not happening?

This came up whilst debuggging a massive set of SQL calcs where EXP(SUM(LOG())) is used to accumulate data within an if clause.  I can alter the code to stop that happening again, but why is it evaluating something within an IF clause that is not met.

Cheers.

EDIT:  Additional amusement. Try catch? Pffft

```
    IF 1=2
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT SQRT(-1)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        END CATCH
    END
```

Non mathematical:

```
    IF 1=2
    BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING('hello',-1,-1)
    END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that `log(0)` is effectively evaluated prematurely due to [constant-folding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933%28SQL.105%29.aspx) whereas `1/0` is not, either due to its cardinality estimation or more likely the fact that the ANSI_WARNINGS setting will affect the desired result of a divide by zero (overflow vs NULL).

Comment: ANSI warnings made no difference, but that is the link I think I needed so thanks muchly :)

Comment: Your welcome. By ANSI_WARNINGS I meant that if a "set ansi_warnings off" were issued at any time then you would not see a divide by zero error. Since the compiler can never know in advance the state of the ANSI_WARNINGS flag when the compiled query runs, it must ignore any folded expression that raises a divide by zero exception at compile time as it cant predict the desired behaviour. (If ansi_warnings was guaranteed to always be off 1/0 would fold to NULL)

Answer (score 2):

The parser simply doesn't have the smarts to follow your IF logic. Consider the following example:

```
IF (1 = 0)
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE #t(x INT):
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
   CREATE TABLE #t(x INT):
END
```

Whether you execute it or even just parse it, the parser looks at all of the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the batch and determines that you tried to create the table twice (the first copy obviously doesn't have to exist for this to happen). Result:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 
> There is already an object named
>   '#t' in the database.

I don't really know if I have a better answer for you than the parser is not as smart as you.

You can defeat the parser by deferring the problem until runtime by using dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
IF 'hell' = 'freezing over'
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT log(0);';
END
```

But then I'd have to wonder, what is the point of setting up the scaffolding for a condition that will never be true, and issuing a statement that you know is going to error?

Comment: There are about 5 IF conditions.  In one of them a calculation is done on data that in the other conditions will cause errors.

 These examples are trivial to show the behaviour.  It was more like 
IF [Data won't cause error]
  "Do calc"
END

Comment: Also, interestingly it parses fine, but does not execute successfully

Comment: Yes the parser doesn't always catch all types of errors in advance, and catches some in advance that would never be errors at runtime. As I said, it's not the smartest. But it does have a *lot* of complex rules and algorithms to determine what it will allow to parse successfully and what it won't. These rules are not documented so as @GordonLinoff explained you just have to know what kind of things will trip up the parser and what kind of things it will let slide.

Answer (score 2):

> If I attempt to **run** it I am expecting SQL to jump past the IF clause and move to the end.

When you run your batch three things happen

1. Your SQL is parsed
2. Your SQL is compiled
3. Your SQL is executed

What's unfortunate is that both compile and execution errors in a batch in SQL server result in the same "Query Completed with errors" message. So lets use a Procedure where its easier to see the difference

Consider the following

```
Create proc compiletime
as 
 SELECT log(0)
 SELECT SQRT(-1)
 SELECT SUBSTRING('hello',-1,-1)
 SELECT 1/0
```

That procedure parses fine. However it can't be compiled unless we remove the first thre SELECTs because we have some constants that are invalid as parameters.  It would be nice if `SELECT 1/0` also caused a compile time error instead of a run time error but as @Alex K points out the behavior is based on ANSI_WARNINGS so its not a compile time error.

So that's why we see differences between when the first two. It also explains why TRY CATCH didn't work since its a compile time error.

Now why does SQL server compile unreachable code. Because *in general* in order to know that it's unreachable requires a solution to the halting problem. You can solve it for some cases but then this ...

```
DECLARE @x as integer
SET @x = SomeFunction()
If (1 = @x)
   SomeCompiletime error
```

would have different behavior which is even more confusing.

```
if (1=0)
   SomeCompiletime error
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, there are some expressions that the SQL compiler is trying to evaluate at compile time versus at run time.  My guess is that a division is considered not too expensive, so it postpones it to the run time.  On the other hand, something really complicated like a log() is expensive and they want to do it at compile time.

This is a guess.  It also means that such differences are non-deterministic.  You have to figure out which one work or don't work in a particular script -- and the behavior may change between releases of the database.