# SQL query doesn't allow me to Select Into with If Else

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a stored procedure that changes the `SELECT` statement based on a variable. The code errors out saying the temp table already exists. I don't understand how to fix this.

Please help!

```
DECLARE @Lotnum varchar(30);
DECLARE @FormulationID varchar(30); 
DECLARE @QtyToProduce numeric(18, 2); 
DECLARE @JobType varchar(2); 

DECLARE @TotalToDisp numeric(18, 2);
DECLARE @ContReq INT;
DECLARE @CONTCODE varchar(30);
DECLARE @CONTMAXQUANT INT;

SET @Lotnum = 'I23-01134';
SET @FormulationID = 'NPI-401-50F';
SET @QtyToProduce = 50;
SET @JobType = 'IN';
    
BEGIN
    IF @JobType = 'IN'
        BEGIN
        PRINT 'jOB tYPE IS iNK';

        SELECT 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_SOLDBYGALLON, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_WPG, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_DEFAULTBATCHSIZE, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.ComponentItemCode, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS,
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS / MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS AS QTYRECPERUM,
            @QtyToProduce as TotalQTY,
            ROUND((MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS / MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS) * MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_WPG * @QtyToProduce, 4) AS ExtendedQTY,
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PAGEGRP, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_TUBGROUP,
            LEFT(MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo, 16) AS CondensedFormulationID,
            @Lotnum AS LotNum 
        INTO
            #TempProdQuatities
        FROM            
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail  
        INNER JOIN
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader ON MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.BillNo = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo 
                                      AND MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.Revision = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision
        WHERE
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo = @FormulationID 
            AND MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PAGEGRP = 3 
            AND MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_TUBGROUP = 500 
            AND MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.Revision = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision ;
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'jOB tYPE IS sOMETHING eLSE';
    
        SELECT 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_SOLDBYGALLON, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_WPG, MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_DEFAULTBATCHSIZE, 
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.ComponentItemCode, MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS,
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS/MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS as QTYRECPERUM,
            @QtyToProduce as TotalQTY,
            Round((MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PARTS/MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_TOTPARTS) * MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.UDF_WPG * @QtyToProduce,4) as ExtendedQTY,
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PAGEGRP, MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_TUBGROUP,
            Left(MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo,16) as CondensedFormulationID,
            @Lotnum as LotNum 
            into #TempProdQuatities
        FROM            
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail INNER JOIN
            MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader ON MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.BillNo = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo 
            AND MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.Revision = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision
            Where MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.BillNo = @FormulationID and MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_PAGEGRP = 3 and MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillDetail.UDF_TUBGROUP = 500 
            and MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.Revision = MAS_LPI.dbo.BM_BillHeader.CurrentBillRevision ;
        END
END
```

I am dropping the table if it exists but still getting errors.  Not sure how to make this work.

Comment: Don't use same name or use dynamic sql or dont use select into and create table first

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703937/61305) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622186/61305).

Comment: Wouldn't adding a `drop table if exists #tablename` solve your problem?